# jQuery $.each with appended elements, need to push appended element in initial loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

As you can see in the excerpt of my code below, I am running a loop to fetch IDs of all li items. Problem is the li elements are appended after an ajax callback. Obviously, the newly appended elements are not included in my initial loop and therefore any clicks, focus events I have do not work. What is the best way to "refresh" the items in my loop? I have tried enclosing the loop in a function and calling it in the ajax callback but it's not working.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<ul id="post-list">
    <li id="post-1"></li>
    <li id="post-2"></li>
    <li id="post-3"></li>
    <li id="post-4"></li>
    <li id="post-5"></li>
</ul>

var $postlist = $("#post-list > li");

$postlist.each(function(idx, li) {

    var list = $(li);
    var $postID = list.attr('id').replace('post-','');

    console.log($postID);
});
```

Comment: calling it in the success handler of the ajax function, after the elements have been appended, should work fine.

Comment: Also, `$` in front of variables typically mean a jQuery object, you could shorten this code up to two lines in the `each` by referencing `this` as well.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I think you should be careful placing numbers as ids, it's really easy to get dups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you store your jQuery array in `$postlist` the array is not changed by updates to the DOM.  Instead, collect the `<li>` elements each time you run your code:

```
var $postlist = $("#post-list");

$postlist.children("li").each(function() {

    var list = $(this);
    var $postID = list.attr('id').replace('post-','');

    console.log($postID);
});
```

`this` refers to the DOM element itself inside the `each` loop so you can leave out the function parameters if you don't need the array index of the element.

To add events to elements that do not exist yet, set the event listener on the parent object  with the jQuery `on()` method:

```
$postlist.on("click","li",function(){

    console.log('clicked: ' + $(this).attr('id'));

});
```